# Unique Key and Index - Should I use both

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some "phone numbers", "zip codes" and "house numbers", so they are Unique in the table (phone X can only be at zipcode Y and house number Z one time ) so I created a unique key with these 3 together, but I also want to search for a phone number, find which phones are in a zipcode.

So... Should I use a unique key for the 3 combined and create one index for each or the unique key already does the job to search only for a specific number ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that under the hood, MySQL implements unique keys as indexes with the additional constraint that the column or columns comprising the index must be unique.

In your particular case, I wouldn't create any additional indexes. The unique key should cover you nicely for phone number lookup and phone number / zip code look up.

If you're worried that perhaps your query isn't using the key to do the lookup, pop the keyword `EXPLAIN` in front of the query and MySQL will display the "query plan", which will include information about which keys/indexes are being used for that query. It should be pretty easy to find articles on the web that explain how to interpret this output.

Answer (score 1):

keys (indexes) are only useful from `left-most` towards the right up until the column that is *not* used (but in the index) in that query down that index path.

For single column indexes, naturally, there is only one left-most column for that index.

A composite key in mysql is a key that is a **combination** of more than one column. The key itself can be a unique key (a unique combination of the columns is allowed, but only 1 row of data as such).

So if you have a composite key on(a,b,c), it is useful for just `a`, for `a` and `b` together, or all three. But only partially if searching for `a` and `c` together. Partially, meaning, after its use for `a`, it converts into a non-index search (as a `where`) thereafter to pick up `c`. So it gets you close, but almost a mini or micro table scan thereafter, to coin a phrase.

One will often have a few composite keys, flipping around the left-most weighted column. But everything comes at a cost. Searching is great. It slows inserts and updates.

Please see the Manual page [Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) to read more. And focus on the `left-most` concept of it.

And keep your composite indexes thin. Three `int` columns in a composite can be great if used well. A few larger `varchars` in there, bad.

---

Whatever you do, don't fool yourself into thinking that just because you create an index that it will be used. That can only be determined through the use of tools such as the [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) facility in mysql. If they are not used, you just slowed down all those inserts and updates. See also the article [Using Explain to Write Better Mysql Queries](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/).